# I am not able to understand the different flags and things used in 'make' file

Tags: linux

`export LIB="../../libip_8.a"`

`export FFLAGS="-O3 -openmp -auto -threads -recursive -i8 -r8"`

`export AFLAGS=" "`

`export CFLAGS=" -O3 -m64"`

can someone explain me all this flag used and about this recursive and all.

Comment: Have you tried to Google them? First look for `FFLAGS`, `CFLAGS`, etc. Understand what they are used for. Then look into the specific parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, usage and effects of environment variables depend on the make rules where a specific variable appears; to understand what e. g. `LIB` does, you have to look where and how `LIB` is used in the makefile or in the predefined rules (which `make -p` displays).

That said, you can assume that

- `LIB` contains additional libraries to be searched for needed variables and functions and potentially linked to a program
- `FFLAGS` contains flags for the FORTRAN compiler, possibly [ifort](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/linux_clusters/man/ifort.txt)
- `CFLAGS` contains flags for the C compiler.